# AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'RegexField'. python (django)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-3.0

I want add RegexField but i have this error. why? 
found it on Google but there is nothing on regexfield

**this is error**

***mob = models.RegexField(regex=r'^+?1?\d{9,15}$')
AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'RegexField'***

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django import forms


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """Define a model manager for User model with no username field."""

    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a User with the given email and password."""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a regular User with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractUser):
    """User model."""

    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    mob = models.RegexField(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$')


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()
```

Comment: A `RegexField` is a *formfield*, not a model field. The regex is validated in the form, not in the model.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem how fix in forms.py?

Answer (score 3):

A [**`RegexField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/fields/#regexfield) is a *form* field. You can use it in a form to validate text before you for example store it in a model, but not in a *model*.

What you *can* do is add a [**`RegexValidator`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/validators/#django.core.validators.RegexValidator) as validator to your model field:

```
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

class User(AbstractUser):
    """User model."""

    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    mob = models.CharField(
        max_length=17,
        validators=[RegexValidator(r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$')]
    )


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()
```

As of [django-2.2](/questions/tagged/django-2.2) you can also make use of the [*constraint framework* <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/constraints/) to validate constraints at the database layer. Not all databases per se check constraints, so it is *not* guaranteed to validate it at the database layer. You can define a constraint with:

```
from django.db.models import Q
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

class User(AbstractUser):
    """User model."""

    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    mob = models.CharField(
        max_length=17,
        validators=[RegexValidator(r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$')]
    )


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=Q(mob__regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$'),
                name='mob_valid'
            ),
        ]
```

You can also define a form with `RegexField`, although if you add a validator that is not necessary. For example in a form you can add:

```
from django import forms

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    mob = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Thanks but also the letters that are written? I just want the numbers to be

Comment: @kokiwebaa: what do you mean with the numbers. The regex will be validated if you enter data through a form (a form will call `.clean_fields` and run the validators). So if does contain non-digit chars (that is not `+`), it will raise an error. In fact a `RegexField` is just a `CharField`, that adds a validator, so there is nothing "special" about `RegexField`, it is basically a "shortcut".

Comment: i want only phone numbers and don't letter

Comment: @kokiwebaa: well that will be checked by the form... Since we added a `RegexValidator` to the validators fo the `CharField`. So if you enter a `foo` in the input field, then the form will reject it.